# codeigniter mail not sending

Tags: codeigniter, email

This the function in my controller, which is called:

```
public function sendContact()
{
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $to_email = $this->main_model->get_account_email();
    $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $message = $this->input->post('message');

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
    $this->email->to($to_email); 
    $this->email->subject('Contact');
    $this->email->message($message);    
    $this->email->send();
}
```

I get no errors, but the mail isn't incomming in the mailbox.
When i do a print, everything seems to be fine..

In another controller, this code is working fine, my host supports mailing..

I've been looking so long to it, what an I overlooking?

Comment: Have you checked your junk folder? It might have worked somewhere else but certain keywords could make it trigger.

Comment: Hi BeatAlex, you are right, maybe a bit dumb of me, but it's indeed in my junk folder. Probably as you explained, the keyword 'test' in the message must have caused it.

Comment: Haha we've all done it! Good to know your code works fine!